# how to get number of how much the string is common in a array

Tags: php, arrays

Hey I have an array with a bunch of data

I did a `array_count_values`, and now I've got something like this:

```
$bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
arsort($bots); 

Array ( ["abc"] => 9 ["xyz"] => 1 )
```

I just want to get the number.  So just the 9.

Does someone can tell me how do I get just the number?

Comment: i dont know why but stackoverflow tells me evertime i'm writing something wrong -.- so i need to post some of my text in {}

Comment: What array are you printing to get `Array ( ["abc"] => 9 ["xyz"] => 1 )`?

Comment: array_count_values() tells u no. of occurrences of a value . If you want count all the values in an array use count($arrayname)

Comment: count($array) just count the number of all values in the array.. not of just single parts of it

Comment: Its Pretty Unclear. What you want to achieve over here

Comment: Do you want to only have the values? If you want 9, what about 1?

Comment: i dont care about 1 - i just need the number of the most commom string in the array - i want to save a : Top abc -

Comment: As you are already sorting it, you can get the first element using `current()` checkout the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bots = array_count_values($all_bots);
arsort($bots)
echo current($bots);
```

Comment: wow this works perfect.. i did so many complicated other things.. thanks alot !

Comment: Me and people with the same problem will really appreciate if you accept this answer using the tick mark ;)

Comment: Thanks, perfect,  @Evolution48 I think it's a complete answer, you could answer it

Answer (score 0):

After sorting you can get the *first* value with `current()`. However, I'd suggest forgoing the sort operation and using `max` instead:

```
$mostOccuring = max(array_count_values($all_bots));
```

This produces the same result a lot more efficiently. Obviously you won't get the string itself though ("abc").